# Its not showing all stages when I am opening any opportunity under Sales in openerp

Tags: odoo

I have created some new stages under Opportunities in openERP,when I am using kanban view its showing all the stages but when I am using form view or opening any opportunity its not showing all the stages.
plz help me bcoz I am new in openERP.

Comment: I am using openerp 7 plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't added your new state in `statusbar_visible` attribute.

Like this: `statusbar_visible="draft,sent,done"`